# Keep absolutely positioned div centered in relation to container not screen

Tags: html, css

So I have an absolute positioned `div`that is **centered to screen size** from the **left** and the **top**.

Update: See the demo here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJmdJo

```
.middle {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

[image]

So for example the user is browsing the page with a small sized phone on landscape mode. (screen height shrinks)

[image]

The `div` overlaps as expected and that's not we wanted. **This is the result I'm looking for**:

[image]

`div`'s height should stop getting smaller than our `header`'s height.
The sticky footer should also stop exceeding the limit.

Note:
The body's min-height doesn't exist yet. I believe that's something that should be added.
The header is not really a header, it's just the top section of my page, which is a logo and the title of site.

The rest of my code related to other tags, if it matters:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.middle {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="header">Welcome</div>
    <div class="middle">Description</div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Just curious, what happens if the "Description" `div` has a lot of content, in which case, it would overlap the header and probably be under the footer (depending on any z-index values)?

Comment: @MarcAudet Good point, I want to find out about that too though. But in my case it doesn't have. It's just a few lines telling about the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your images, you have the centered div absolutely positioned in relation to the entire containing block. So it's always going to center in relation to that container.

If you want to keep the centered div within the light gray area, you then need to assign a `position: relative` to that section, and then make the centered `div` a child element of the light gray element. Then, the offsets of the absolute positioning will be in relation to the light gray box.

---

**UPDATE** (based on comments and revised question)

It seems the problem you are having is caused primarily by combining both fixed heights (pixels) and relative heights (percentages). If you use only percentage heights in your div containers, the page will scale smoothly.

Try these adjustments to your CSS:

```
.logo {
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("... omitted for demo...") no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 20%; /* changed from 80px; */
    width: 80px;
}

.middle {
  position:relative;
  height: 60%; /* changed from 100% */
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%; /* changed from 50px */
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGQPBN)

Comment: You mean I should wrap my centered div inside a container that has `position relative` ? But then it wouldn't be centered to the total screen size but it's container. Also the header doesn't have a fixed height. It changes based on media queries.

Comment: The code in your question doesn't match the images or replicate the problem you're describing. That's why I based my answer on the images only. If there are other considerations we should take into account please post below or update the question.

Comment: Thx for jsfiddle link, that's very close but its not what i am trying to achieve. Sorry I failed to replicate it myself. Let me explain. This is a mobile first design. I have a logo on top with a title below it, and then a text describing the site in the center, and then a footer with login and register buttons. Try visiting something Twitter or Tumblr in mobile and you will exactly get the idea of my page layout. The problem is that if we visit the page on a a very small screen, or view it on landscape mode, my centered div will overlap the logo, the title and it all get messed up.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. Is it possible to put the code you have in a fiddle demo? That way I and others can see what code is causing the problem and hopefully provide you with the right adjustments.

Comment: Ok I think this is it. Sorry if its ugly. Try resizing your window to see the problem http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGQEJv

Comment: Right. And the reason that's happening is because you have the centered div absolutely positioned in relation to the viewport. You're telling the centered div (with your CSS) to always stay 50% from the top (`top: 50%`). Hence, regardless of screen size, it will always stay 50% from the top.

Comment: Yes. But I think we could have some sort of minimum height, can't we? As I said, if you inspect a site like Twitter or Tumblr on device mode, and then resize the  screen, You can see the text always stays in the center and nothing overlaps at all. Its looks like from a certain point they set a minimum height kinda of rule, So the layout get fixed and you just get scrollbars.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87206/discussion-between-xperator-and-michael-b).